# The component template do not shows up, it render to the `<!---->`

Tags: vue.js

I have a `forget-pwd.vue` component:

```
<template>

  <div class="page-common">
    ABC
  </div>

</template>

<script>


</script>

<style scoped>    

</style>
```

in the router.js, there is my route:

```
export const paths = {
  home: '/',
  dataCenter: '/data-center',
  forgetPassword: '/forget-password',

}


export const app_routes = [
  ......
  {
    path: paths.forgetPassword,
    name: '忘记密码',
    meta: {
      title: ''
    },
    component: (resolve) => require(['./views/忘记密码/forget-pwd.vue'], resolve)
  },

];

export const routes = [
  ...app_routes,
];
```

this is my `index.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="index">
    <i-header ></i-header>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <i-footer></i-footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import Home from './首页/home.vue'
  import Header from '../components/header/header.vue'
  import Footer from '../components/footer/footer.vue'


  export default {
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {



    },

    components: {
      'home': Home,
      'i-header': Header,
      'i-footer': Footer,

    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>

  .index {

  }

</style>
```

in a modal of my `header.vue` I link to the `forget-pwd.vue`:

```
<router-link class="forget-pwd" type="text" to="forgetPwdPath" @click.native="closeModal" >忘记密码?</router-link>
```

the route is skipped, but the `forget-pwd.vue` template do not shows up:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to bind the `to` in your router link. So bind it:

```
<router-link class="forget-pwd" type="text" :to="forgetPwdPath" @click.native="closeModal" >忘记密码?</router-link>
```

Or

```
<router-link class="forget-pwd" type="text" v-bind:to="forgetPwdPath" @click.native="closeModal" >忘记密码?</router-link>
```

Comment: Why `<router-link class="forget-pwd" type="text" to="/" ...`  this router-link do not need `bind`?

Comment: @244boy `to`` takes the path as a string. If you just pass `to="/''` you are passing `/` as a string. If you pass `forgotPwdPath` to `to` without binding it considers `forgotPwdPath` as a string. To resolve `forgotPwdPath` which might be a property you need to bind `to`.

Comment: Keep in mind....if you did not bind whatever you pass is a string....if you bind it is javascript and thus resolved